# JavaScript properties with setter methods aren't real properties?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function Name(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.fullName = first + " " + last
}

Name.prototype = {
  get fullName() {
    return this.first + " " + this.last;
  },

  set fullName(name) {
    var names = name.split(" ");
    this.first = names[0];
    this.last = names[1];
  }
};

var person = new Name("Foo", "Bar");
// person.fullName = "Foo Bar"
person.hasOwnProperty("fullName") // false
```

Is there a way to return the properties?

Comment: So, are you just asking why `.hasOwnProperty()` returns `false` in your case?  If so, then maybe you should actually ask that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As InvernoMuto points out, `Object.hasOwnProperty("fullName")` returns `false` because it is not `person`'s own property; it is inherited via the prototype chain. When you use `this.fullName = "...";` in your constructor, you are invoking the inherited setter, not adding a new property.

If you want to find such properties, you can:

1. Use a `for..in` loop:

```
for (var prop in person) {
    // this will iterate over EVERY property in person's prototype chain
}
```

2. Attach the properties in your constructor:

```js
function Name(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;

  Object.defineProperty(this, "fullName", {
    get: function() {
      return this.first + " " + this.last;
    },
    set: function(name) {
      var names = name.split(" ");
      this.first = names[0];
      this.last = names[1];
    }
  });
}

var person = new Name("Ronald", "McDonald");
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty("fullName")); // true
```

3. Create a whole new object in your constructor, using the get/set syntax that you have there. In this case, we wouldn't use the `new` keyword but just call the function:

```js
function Name(first, last) {
    return {
        first: first,
        last: last, 

        get fullName() { return this.first + " " + this.last; },
        set fullName(name) { 
            var names = name.split(" ");
            this.first = names[0];
            this.last = names[1];
        }
    };
};

var person = Name("Ronald", "McDonald");
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty("fullName")); // true
```

Answer (score 6):

hasOwnProperty does not check down the object's prototype chain, in your case person `get` and `set` are inherited through the prototype chain

[**hasOwnProperty**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method.
>   This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in
>   operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.

```js
function Name(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.fullName = first + " " + last;
}
var person = new Name("Foo", "Bar");
console.log(person.fullName);
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty("fullName")); // true
console.log(Name.prototype.hasOwnProperty("fullName")); // false

for (var prop in person) {
    console.log(prop);
}

console.log('');

Name.prototype = {
    get fullName() {
        return this.first + " " + this.last;
    },

    set fullName(name) {
        var names = name.split(" ");
        this.first = names[0];
        this.last = names[1];
    }
};
var person2 = new Name("Foo", "Bar");
console.log(person2.fullName);
console.log(person2.hasOwnProperty("fullName")); // false
console.log(Name.prototype.hasOwnProperty("fullName")); // true
```

Quote @JLRishe

> When you use this.fullName = "..."; in your constructor, you are
>   invoking the inherited setter, not adding a new property.

If you want to find such properties, you can just use a for... in statement:

```
for (var prop in person) {
    console.log(prop);
}
```

Comment: Since yours is the most upvoted answer, I would suggest including an explanation of why `this.fullName = first + " " + last` does not give the new objects their own `fullName` property here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) "The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up." This means that whenever you try to access `fullName` of an instance of `Name` (e.g. `person.fullName`), javascript will delegate to that getter function, which happens to lie on the `Name.prototype` object.

Additionally, "The [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) syntax binds an object property to a function to be called when there is an attempt to set that property." So even though are explicitly giving each instance a `fullName` property, javascript actually looks to that `set` function on the prototype. If you want to get around this, and have `person.hasOwnProperty("fullName")` return true, you could do something like this:

```
function Name(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.fullName = first + " " + last
}

Name.prototype.setFullName = function(fullName){
  var names = fullName.split(" ");
  this.first = names[0];
  this.last = names[1];
  this.fullName = fullName;
};

var person = new Name("Foo", "Bar");
// person.fullName = "Foo Bar"
person.hasOwnProperty("fullName") // true
```